# Transform list to list of consecutive elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Any idea how i could do the following in python >3.7 ?

```
a = ["a","b","c","c","a","a","a"]
b = F(a) => [[0],[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

The use case is a list with roughly 10e6 elements.
Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC, one approach:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

a = ["a","b","c","c","a","a","a"]
counter = count()

res = [[next(counter) for _ in vs] for _, vs in groupby(a)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[0], [1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

An alternative using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a = ["a","b","c","c","a","a","a"]
res = [[v for v, _ in vs] for k, vs in groupby(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1))]
print(res)
```

Comment: Too fast!! :D great solution

Comment: sigh, I was too late :)) also captcha on my way

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a","b","c","c","a","a","a"]
res = []
prev_item = None
for i, item in enumerate(a):
    if item == prev_item:
        res[-1].append(i)
    else:
        res.append([i])
    prev_item = item
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in comparing the three approaches (loop vs functional vs functional enumerate). It seemed to me that the functional approach traverses the list two times (first with groupby and then for reducing the group, not the whole list at once but piece by piece traversing two times). So just for your reference posting the results, I think they are interesting in educational purposes.

Here is the code for comparison:

```
from itertools import groupby, count
from operator import itemgetter
import random

random.seed(0)

input_letter = ["a", "b", "c"]

a = [random.choice(input_letter) for _ in range(100000)]

def loop_approach(a: list) -> list:
    res = []
    prev_item = None
    for i, item in enumerate(a):
        if item == prev_item:
            res[-1].append(i)
        else:
            res.append([i])
        prev_item = item    
    return res

def functional_approach(a:list) -> list:

    counter = count()

    return [[next(counter) for _ in vs] for _, vs in groupby(a)]


def functional_enumerate_approach(a:list) -> list:
    return [[v for v, _ in vs] for k, vs in groupby(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1))]

assert loop_approach(a) == functional_approach(a)
assert loop_approach(a) == functional_enumerate_approach(a)

%timeit loop_approach(a)
%timeit functional_approach(a)
%timeit functional_enumerate_approach(a)
```

Output:

```
7.23 ms ± 93.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
12.7 ms ± 63.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
13 ms ± 150 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

In other words, although functional approach is no doubt more concise and beautiful, loop makes it roughly two times faster